# Cases in strings, Pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

In pseudocode, how do I convert and switch between upper and lower cases of letters in strings? 
I am trying to convert a code that is in C sharp to pseudocode :

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't even tried anything, yet, because I'm not sure of the function/terminology used in pseudocode for "ToLower", in C sharp.

Comment: Are you asking what is the _syntax_ for "CONVERT STRING TO LOWER CASE" within Pseudocode? Uhh, what I just wrote would suffice. [Pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) is just an informal way to write out programming logic, there isn't any actual language. So you might convert your attached image to the following Pseudocode: `Set variable "test" to "HELLO world"; Convert "test" to lowercase and store value in "test" variable; Print "test" to screen; Read input from the user`

Answer (score 0):

Because it's pseudo code, you can do it pretty much however you want.

For instance

```
test := lower(test)
```

Or

```
test ← test in lowercase
```

As long as the code is understandable and somewhat consistent, it's fine.

If you want to switch between lower and upper case in a string, making the text **LoOk LiKe ThIs** you could do it with the following code.

```
for i ← 1 to length(test) do
    if i is even do
        test[i] ← lower(test[i])
    else do
        test[i] ← upper(test[i])
```

Comment: thank you, Johan. But what if I wanted to convert a word. Where it would have one letter lowercase, and one higher case. From user input.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want your output to look like. Can you clarify what you want `HELLO this is a Test Sentence` to look like after the operation? Do you want it to be like `HeLlO tHiS iS ...`?